# fetch results by date in a specific range repeated every N days

Tags: mysql, repeat, date-range

Assuming the following data:

```
+--------------------------+
| id | created_at          |
+--------------------------+
| 1  | 2019-04-23 13:01:00 |
| 2  | 2019-04-23 13:18:00 |
| 3  | 2019-04-30 13:01:00 |
| 4  | 2019-04-30 13:06:00 |
| 5  | 2019-04-30 13:17:00 |
| 6  | 2019-04-30 13:23:00 |
| 7  | 2019-04-30 13:32:00 |
| 8  | 2019-05-04 13:19:00 |
| 9  | 2019-05-04 13:41:00 |
| 10 | 2019-05-04 13:51:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

I'd like to fetch entries where `created_at` was in a 15 minutes window 
 3 days ago OR every repeated 7 days in the past from `NOW()`

For example, if i'm running the query at `2019-05-07 13:30:00`, I would like to fetch entries #2 (within 14 days ago + 15 minutes), #5 (within 7 days ago + 15 minutes) and #8 (within 3 days ago + 15 minutes).

I can easily write the 3 days condition, but i'm struggling with the repeated 7 days condition.

My query so far :

```
SELECT id, created_at
FROM user_abstract
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, created_at, NOW()) BETWEEN 3*24*60 AND 3*24*60+15
```

I created a fiddle with the above dataset and the query so far, where NOW() can be customized for testing: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xa4ZEqEcGUDa2N3MLrgvh3/0

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
SET @now = '2019-05-07 13:30:00';
SELECT id, created_at
FROM user_abstract
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, created_at, NOW()) BETWEEN 3*24*60 AND 3*24*60+15
or MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, created_at, @now),7*24*60) <= 15
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditions you are trying to apply are distinct so these conditions are must apply, I made changes in your query(6th entry lies in 2nd mentioned range)

```
SET @now = '2019-05-07 13:30:00';
SELECT id, created_at
FROM user_abstract
WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, created_at, @now) BETWEEN 3*24*60 AND 3*24*60+15) OR
MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, created_at, @now),7*24*60) <= 15
```

Working [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/22EsJbqx7mPxuYoXcK4Pmh/0).

Comment: He asks it for multiples of 7 days, not only 7 and 14. See my answer instead

Comment: Oops pardon mate, I will make changes as per that

Comment: it works amazingly well. I started doing some job with Modulo, but couldn't consolidate it. thank guys. I will credit @xavier for the accepted answer, he was the first to provide the MOD answer